# How can I set a timeout around some code in java on the main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout

I'm looking for functionality in java identical to this in ruby:

SystemTimer.timeout_after(30.seconds) do
   do something
end

i could achieve this by forking a thread and then killing it after a while, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: Be sure to read http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Answer (score 2):

Cant you just use the Java [Timer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)?

> A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), which has an [invokeAll](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method who recievs a timeout as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [`CompletableFuture<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) (Link leads to official JavaDoc) from Java 8.

Usage could look something like this:

```
public static <V> Optional<V> of(PrivilegedAction<V> action, Duration duration) {

    final CompletableFuture<V> handler = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> action.run());
    V retval = null;
    try {
        retval = handler.get(duration.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException te) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            handler.cancel(true);
        } catch (CancellationException ce) {
        }
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(retval);
}
```

A util class I created: (German comments) [DTimeout](http://pastebin.com/Ra7yr9eF) (View at pastebin)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score -1):

Either run it in a Thread or do something like this:

```
void method() {
    long endTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
    while (true) {
        // method logic
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > endTimeMillis) {
            // do some clean-up
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this doesn't work for all kind of methods.